# QLcdNumber strange behavior

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5, qwidget

Well, the value of QLcdNumber is set using the display() property. For the first time dealing with QLcdNumber shows a strange behavior.
Consider this example:

```
void MainWindow::dataFromUdp(QByteArray pack)
{
    if(pack.at(0) == '!')
    {
        unsigned long x;

        x = (unsigned char)pack[pack.length() -1] +
                (unsigned char)pack[pack.length() -2] * 256 +
                (unsigned char)pack[pack.length() -3] * 256 * 256 +
                (unsigned char)pack[pack.length() -4] * 256 * 256 * 256;

        //extract packet

        if(x == crcCalculate(0, pack.length() - 4, pack))  
        {
            //CRC is correct

            if(pack[1] == 0x0d)
            {
                number = 0;   // class member variable
                char value[6];
                sprintf(value,"%c%c%c%c%c", (char)pack[2],(char)pack[3],(char)pack[4],
                        (char)pack[5],(char)pack[6]);  

//Now value = 00125

                number = atoi(value)/1000.0;

//Now value is 0.125

                ui->lcd_range->display(number);

                qDebug() << number;

//Here qDebug() and qlcd both show -3.6xx
```

do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you sure the `value = 00125`? `QLcdNumber::display()` call can't change the number as the parameter is passed to it by value. Also, what type is the `number` field?

Comment: that is what I get in debug mode. the type of number is float.

Comment: Another (final) guess is maybe `number` is changed in other thread.

Answer (score 0):

The server was sending me a second packet as well mistakenly. So, the second packet overwrote the lcd without eye noticing it! I am sorry for taking your time.

Cheers.